# phpMyAdmin not getting started from Linux CentOS?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

I have installed **MySQL server** on Linux CentOS server with the command -

**sudo yum install mysql**

I am able to start the Mysqld service. Then I have installed **phpMyAdmin** with the command

**sudo yum install phpmyadmin**

I have changed the **config.inc.php** file for the configuration. Then I have restarted the **httpd** service. Also I have changed the **iptables** to give access to mysql port 3306.

But still I am not able to get started **phpMyAdmin** on the browser.

Also I didnt set the password for **root** user but when I connect to mysql through command line it asks for the password. I tried with blank password but it is now working.

So please can anybody suggest me how to start **phpMyAdmin** and get connected to **mysql** ?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin is supposed to works flawlessly, I usually installed from the official website after get installed MySQL and PHP. So, have you installed PHP already?

In negative case, you have to do it before run phpMyAdmin.

```
sudo yum install php5 php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your SELinux is blocking it. I have seen this before with things I have done where SELinux has stopped me accessing it. Running `sestatus` will tell you.

To disable it, edit the file `/etc/selinux/config` so SELINUX is set to disabled. Then restart your server and run `sestatus` to check.